# How to make text written on the image when decreasing the screen size

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I am facing a problem in which I want the content which is written on the left half of the screen should be written on the image which is on the right side when decreasing the screen size.

for reference, check the image as I want this [problem image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/93kXc.jpg)
to be like this  [Solution image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qV4rt.jpg) when I decrease the size of my screen, But my screen looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KJRYB.jpg) at present. I need the solution as soon as possible.

Note: I used mostly pre-defined classes of bootstrap4 for this.

code is-

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col p-0 col-6 bg-creame" style="height: 100vh;">
    <div class="h-100 d-flex flex-column justify-content-start pt-5">
      <div class="m-5 pt-5 pr-5">
        <h1 class="mb-5"><b style="font-weight: 900;"><b>Contact</b></b></h1>
        <p class="m-0" style="font-weight: 900;font-size: 18px;">Email Address</p>
        <p><a style="color: inherit !important;font-size: 23px;" href="mailto:support@regid.ca">support@XXX.com</a>
        </p>
        <p class="m-0 mt-5" style="font-weight: 900;font-size: 18px;">Mailing Address</p>
        <p style="font-size: 23px;">
          XXXXXX, 77 XXXX XXX X,
          XXXXXX, XX XXX 6XX
        </p>

        <div class="d-none d-lg-block">
          <button class="text-uppercase btn pr-5 pl-5 color-creame bg-orange"
            style="border-radius: 50px; letter-spacing: 1px;font-size: 20px;">
            Contact Us
          </button>
        </div>

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col p-0 col-6 bg-orange" style="height: 100vh;">
    <div style="position: absolute; bottom: 0; right: 0;">
      <div class="h-50 bg-orange d-flex flex-column justify-content-end" style="padding-top: 14rem;">
        <div class="text-center p-4">
          <i class="fas fa-arrow-up bg-black" style="font-size: 2rem;"></i>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="d-flex flex-column h-100">
      <img height="100%" width="100%" src="./assets/img/Rectangle 8 (2).png" class="img img-responsive">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Show us your code

Comment: I added my code, check it. And suggest me a good answer. It will be very helpful for me.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `z-index` to push the image behind the text and do something like this

```
@media (max-width: 600px) {
  img {
    width: 100%;
    z-index: -1;
  }

  div {
    z-index: 1;
  }
}
```

Comment: Your answer looks good, but can you answer this more specifically by watching the code.